# What is the shortest English–language sentence which contains 25 unique letters?

Tags: no-computers, language

There is a lot of literature on the subject of short English *pangrams*, that is, sentences that contain every letter.

But I am curious what the shortest, or at least some of the shortest, sentences are that are not so strictly defined. I would like a sentence that contains at least 25 unique letters, but not necessarily all 26.

For example, the sentence "Quick jigs vex Nymph of Bad Waltz" contains 25 unique letters and has a total length of 27 (that is, 2 characters [in this case 'a' and 'i'] are repeated). Are there valid English sentences that fit this criteria with 26 or even only 25 letters?

Comment: Hey, welcome to Puzzling SE! This seems like an interesting question, but I'm not sure whether it really qualifies as a puzzle. I'm sure some of the older members on this SE will be willing to give a second opinion regarding this, though.

Comment: @Voldemort'sWrath I originally posted this on another SE, but they told me that it would be better–suited here in Puzzling SE.

Comment: To increase the creative puzzling potential, @slondr , you could add a [`no-computers`](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/no-computers) tag

Comment: @humn Great suggestion!

Comment: What counts as an English sentence, exactly? Without precisely specifying that, this question is unfortunately opinion-based, and likely to be closed.

Comment: @Deusovi I would say any sentence made up of words which can be found in a modern English dictionary, and which is grammatically correct from a syntactic point of view (ignoring punctuation, as this puzzle is only concerned with alphabet characters.

Comment: Which dictionary? There are many different dictionaries, which have different entries -- and you may or may not consider these entries words. (Proper nouns? Abbreviations? Terms from other languages that have been loanworded into English? Grammatical constructions with affixes on words that normally don't take them, like "loanworded" in the previous sentence?) You'd need to provide an exact list of the possible words to make it non-subjective. And to specify English syntax is a whole other issue entirely...

Comment: @Sconibulus I believe then the sentence has only 24 unique characters, because that would remove 'Q.'

Comment: @Deusovi I do not have strong opinions on English dictionaries, any reasonably well-circulated one published or updated this decade would be fine.

Comment: A puzzle book I used to have said that the search of 26-letter pangrams leads only to unsatisfying absurdities like "Mr. Jock, TV quiz Ph.D., bags few lynx."

Comment: I think you need to pick on in order for it to be a valid (ie, provable) question.  Perhaps the Scrabble dictionary?  Beyond that, the question is problematic because it's a "shortest" question.  In order to demonstrate an example correct, you'd have to both provide an n-letter example and prove that n-1 was not possible.